# Sending an email without user interaction

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am working on an app that automatically sends me an email message in certain circumstances but
I am unable to automatise the sending of the email, as the message composer picker comes up and I am required to physically press on the Send button...

Is it possible to automatise the "pressure" on the SEND button or does Apple prevent this to avoid spamming maybe?

What are the options for "completion"?

If this is not possible, is it then possible to send the email without using the message picker?

To bring up the message interface I'm using:

```
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

- (void) mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Mail cancelled");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Mail saved");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Mail sent");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Mail sent failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    // Close the Mail Interface
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: you might implement some external back-end service for sending an automatic mail in background – you are not able to send an email without the end-user's explicit confirmation, in background using the standard iOS `MessageUI.framework`.

Comment: As stated, it can't be done entirely from the phone -- you'd have to have a server (one that you maintain) that you route the mail through.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to send an email from the user's mail account without MFMailComposeViewController and user's explicit interaction.

Comment: I was afraid of this...but I do understand that it could be used for spamming. Is there any alternative for in house development that I can use without releasing my app on the store?

Comment: As an alternative, could I completely automatise the uploading of some text file onto my OWN website (obviously setting up user name and password in the app initially)? Do you think Apple would approve this?

Comment: Hey Jeddi - sure, that's exactly what you do.  Sen the file / message / whatever to some external web service (say, Parse.com, or build your own) and have the email sent from there.  That's perfectly fine with Apple.

Comment: Great, thanks! Do you have any advice on where to document myself for using the FTP protocol by myself?